# Updating Logon Hours on a user using C# System.DirectoryServices (windows 2008 Active Directory library)

Tags: c#, active-directory

It's the accessing table of hours on week days... How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this thread on Directory Programming.NET - that's the best information I've found so far (and I've been looking for a while!).

http://directoryprogramming.net/forums/thread/6194.aspx

There's also an article on CodeProject - [LoginHours from DirectoryEntry as a boolean array](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/DirectoryEntry_LoginHours.aspx) - that shows to a certain degree how to work with logon hours from a `DirectoryEntry` object.

Here's [another post](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5324478) which shows how to set the logon hours in Java - might be helpful, too, just to see how they do it.

Comment: The directoryprogramming site says "After more than 6 years of hosting our book's forum, it was unfortunately hacked by some spammers and the database was pretty much destroyed. We are truly sorry to have lost that as a resource with the thousands of posts and answers.

However, if you are just looking for the sample code, we got you covered:" and has only all the sample code

Comment: The java link is broken too, but luckily CodeProject one is still valid

Answer (score 1):

This discussion has a tip regarding the time zone 
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e745e812-1644-491f-9034-39855cd16016/how-to-get-users-login-hours-from-active-directory-using-c?forum=csharpgeneral that is also mentioned a bit at the useful link shared in the other answer http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/DirectoryEntry_LoginHours.aspx

And here you can find more info on accessing this via Account Management API
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.authenticableprincipal.permittedlogontimes(v=vs.110).aspx

some examples on using that API are at
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/90142/Everything-in-Active-Directory-via-C-NET-3-5-Using
but haven't spotted one specific for manipulating the hours

If you use the classic API with LDAP-style attributes, you need to access "logonHours" one judging from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676846(v=vs.85).aspx and https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/6822.active-directory-attributes-in-the-aduc-gui-tool.aspx